# How to be able to send and receive udp packets at the same time?

Tags: c, server, udp, packet

I'm trying to have a server that is able to send packets regularly (every 5 seconds) while still being able to receive incoming packets, answers from the one I've sent and treat them. I have so far been able to achieve the sending of packets reguarly even though I'm unsure if it's the good solution. However, I still don't know if my socket will actually be able to receive packets at the same time.

This is what I've wrote so far:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int rc;
    int sockopt;
    int s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    rc = setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &sockopt,sizeof(int));
    if (rc < 0){
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in6 server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    int p = inet_pton(AF_INET6, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin6_addr);
    if (p < 0){
        perror("inet_pton");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server.sin6_port = htons(2077);
    rc = fcntl(s, F_GETFL);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fcntl\n");exit(1);
    }
    rc = fcntl(s,F_SETFL, rc | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fcntl\n");exit(1);
    }

    char *message = "Netcat\n";
    unsigned char reply[1024];
    memset(reply, 0, sizeof(reply));

    int to = 5;
    struct timeval timeNow;
    struct timeval timeLimit;
    rc = gettimeofday(&timeNow, NULL);
        if (rc < 0){
            perror("gettimeofday");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    rc = gettimeofday(&timeLimit, NULL);
    if (rc < 0){
        perror("gettimeofday - limit");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1){
        if (timeNow.tv_sec - timeLimit.tv_sec >= 5){
            rc = sendto(s,message,7,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
            printf("5 seconds\n");
            gettimeofday(&timeLimit, NULL);
        }
        gettimeofday(&timeNow, NULL);

        rc = recvfrom(s, reply, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (strlen(reply) != 0){
            printf("reply=%s\n", reply);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My goal here would be to send packets every 5 seconds, while still being able to receive incoming ones. I have `netcat` opened in one terminal listening on the ::1/2077, I tried sending a packet to see if my server would receive it by doing `echo "test" | nc -6u -w0 ::1 2077` but netcat received it and not my server.

Do you have any solutions I could use to do that please?

Thanks

Comment: Thread off the recvfrom.

Comment: I sadly have no knowledge on threading in C so far, I'm afraid of using too much time resources and not being able to achieve my goal. I thought about using `select` maybe but I'm unsure on where to use it @MartinJames

Comment: using `select` is what I'd do.  if you're doing things at the speed of events per second it doesn't really matter how you go about it, it's only when you start getting above 10k per second it starts to matter.  that said, your code is "busy waiting" and hence just wasting energy/CPU time.  you're much better off waiting using `select` and calculating a timeout so sleep until you either receive a packet or it's time to send another packet

Comment: So where do you bind to a listening address and port?

Comment: @SamMason I tried using `select`, but there was a delay only once, in other words, it would send a packet, wait the necessary amont of seconds, than it would basically spam packets (I had the code in a `while(1)`. I admit I'm having a hard time using `select`. What do you mean by that: `calculating a timeout so sleep until you either receive a packet or it's time to send another packet` please?

Comment: @Cheatah I thought `bind` wasn't necessary when using UDP (sorry I'm fairly new to networking and C in general.)

Comment: If you set up a server, you need to bind it to obtain a fixed address. How do peers otherwise know how to connect?